# Resource does not exist while calling `GetMemberGroupsAsync`

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;`.

I am calling `GetMemberGroupsAsync` as follows:

```
IEnumerable<string> memberships = client.Groups.GetByObjectId(userObjectId).GetMemberGroupsAsync(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource 'c92da223-a37f-4194-9bbf-74669885a0f0' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."}}}
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Any idea on why does this exception occur and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you intended to get the *user's* member groups? You are now trying to get a group, and then get the group memberships of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates the group you were requesting does not exist.

Based on the code, you were able to acquire the groups with `userObjectId`. Ensure that is a valid group id instead of user id.

Answer (score 0):

It should be rather used as

```
var securityGroupMemberships = client.DirectoryObjects.GetByObjectId(userObjectId).GetMemberGroupsAsync(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This gives all the security groups which a user is part of.